# Using Ajax in Rails 4 to send a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am quite new to rails and I would like to send a background request to the server and then show the results without updating the whole page.

I checked this video: https://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2015/3/18/rails-jquery-ajax. In this video he says it is necessary to create a js view.I also took a look into this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-and-ajax.htm but I am not able to achieve want I want.

Basically the user fills out a form and receive an answer from the controller BUT the values introduced in the form should be there. Because of the entire page refresh the values are reseted.

Routes.rb

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do 

      root 'energycalcmod#front_end'
      get 'energycalcmod/front_end'
      post 'energycalcmod/get_values'

    end
```

energycalcmod_controller.rb

```
class EnergycalcmodController < ApplicationController

    def front_end

    end

    def get_values

        # Receiving the firsts two entries of the formular
        input1 = params[:user_entry_module1].to_i
        input2 = params[:user_entry_module2].to_i           

        @calc = Calculator.new(input1,input2)

        @energy_calc_results = @calc.energy_calc_module_output          

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html {redirect_to "/energycalcmod/front_end"}
            format.js
        end         

    end   

end
```

views/energycalcmod/front_end.html.erb

```
<div id="outer-container" > 
      <div id="input" >
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illum perferendis mollitia at consectetur fuga quasi accusantium iste facere blanditiis nobis, aliquam incidunt impedit unde vitae aliquid dolor sapiente. Architecto, natus!</p> 

        <div id="wrapper-form" >
          <%= render "partials/form" %> 

        </div> 
      </div>

       <div id="optimal" >

      </div>
       <div id="independency" >
      </div>
       <div id="save" >

      </div>     
</div>  

<h3 id="test" style="display:none;" > <%=  @energy_calc_results %> </h3>
```

views/partials/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag("/energycalcmod/get_values", remote: true) do %>

    <div id="upper-form-wrapper" >
        <div id="upper-form-left" >
            <h5 >Jahreshausverbrauch <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" title="Jahreshasuverbrauch"></i></a> </h5>
            <h5 >PV <i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></h5>
        </div>
        <div id="upper-form-right" >
            <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module1", params["user_entry_module1"] || "", id: "jahreshausverbrauch", disable: true, class: "first-input-box", size: 1 %><span>kWh</span>
            <div id="slider-jahreshausverbrauch"></div>

            <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module2", params["user_entry_module2"] || "", id: "pv", disable: true, class: "input-box", size: 1 %><span>kWp</span>
            <div id="slider-pv"></div>
        </div>  
    </div>   

    <%= submit_tag "Berechnen" %> 

<%end%>
```

views/energycalcmod/get_values.js.erb

$("`test").show("<%= j @energy_calc_results %>" );`

Error I got in the console:

```
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken)
```

**Question: I want to post the results `@energy_calc_results` without refreshing the entire page.**

Comment: Have you put  "<%= csrf_meta_tag %>", in your layout?

Comment: Thxs. I added and now I don't get the authenticity error. However, I am not able to print the results in the view. It is missing something. In get_values.js.erb I changed to console.log("<%= @energy_calc_results %>" ); and prints the results in console, but not in the view. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `<%= csrf_meta_tag %>` in layouts and to render results

```
$("#test").html("<%= j @energy_calc_results %>" );
$("#test").show();
```

you are not using id selector in your js.erb file, below-

```
$("test").show("<%= j @energy_calc_results %>" );
```

Thats why results are not showing in page.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I changed but I got this error: `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `gsub' for #<Array:0x007fe6af82a5d0>):
    2: 
    3: 
    4: 
    5:   $("#test").html("<%= j @energy_calc_results %>" );
    6:  $("#test").show();
  app/views/energycalcmod/get_values.js.erb:5:in `_app_views_energycalcmod_get_values_js_erb__394302991091329010_70314381804100'
  app/controllers/energycalcmod_controller.rb:33:in `get_values'
  app/middleware/catch_json_parse_errors.rb:8:in `call'´

Comment: You should have a partial and then render partial with `@energy_calc_results` like - `$("#test").html("<%= j(render :partial => 'energy_calc') %>" );` something like this.

Comment: You sir are the man! I am very thankful.  It was missing the partial (_energy_calc.html.erb) -> <%= @energy_calc_results %> I am very new to ruby.